# Change in pH/acidity of vinegar after adding aqueous NaCl

Tags: acid-base, ph

There's a question in my (grade 10) textbook asking to determine what will happen to the pH/acidity of vinegar if a solution of sodium chloride in distilled water is added to it drop by drop. The answer in the back says the pH will remain unchanged because $\ce{NaCl}$ will dissociate into $\ce{Na^+}$ and $\ce{Cl^-}$ ions, which are neither acidic nor basic.

This explanation doesn't really make much sense to me; wouldn't the water present in the aqueous solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ dilute the ethanoic acid in vinegar to increase the pH/reduce the acidity? Or, at least, wouldn't all the ions formed after dissociation interact with each other to change the pH in some other way?

Comment: The question may have different answers, depending on how deep through a rabbit hole you want or are expected to go.  I assume for the 10th grade, you can say the pH will not change. // The advanced answer would say it depends on which activity coefficient of respective ions decreases with the ionic strength faster.

Comment: The pH increases, as a more diluted solution has a lower oxonium ion concentration, as you pointed out. However, this dependence is not linear in any way

Comment: P.S.: and yes, diluting of vinegar by water or NaCl solution does increase pH, as there is lower acetic acid concentration.

Comment: For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) as a comfortable method to add chemical equations and report numerical values (`\pu{}`) including a non-breakable space.

Comment: In summary, it depends on the initial concentration of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts are absolutely correct, when being absolutely precise. If one diluted vinegar (5% ethanoic acid) with an equal quantity of plain water *or* salt water, there certainly would be a noticeable pH change.

However, if one has a moderate size sample, perhaps 100 mL, and adds salt water drop-by-drop, it's doubtful even a precision pH meter or very sensitive pH indicator would resolve the small change. After all, a drop is defined as [0.05 mL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_(unit)), about 1/2,000 of the original sample.

The answer *is* open ended. What if the original sample were only a single drop, 50 µL?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Is it safe to assume that the ions won't react with each other to form any new compounds that may change the pH?

Comment: No it is not safe to assume anything. Each situation should be analysed.